# Change "Invalid password, please try again" text on graphical login screen

Tags: login-screen

Is there any way to actually do this? I've been searching for answers but its mostly just people asking how to do it at a terminal login prompt or with an incorrect sudo password.

I'm on Ubuntu 17.04

Comment: Do you wnat to change the text, or do you want to know how to enter a correct password ?

Comment: @SorenA I think the title of the question makes that clear enough: *Change “Invalid password, please try again” **text** on graphical login screen*.

Comment: Apparently not, since no one are answering ...